# UIScrollView start another position

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiscrollview, scrollview, resolution

I have project is single view app and add to view controller scrollview
with parameters

```
[scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(0, 960)];
```

if screen resolution is 320x480 then we have some invisible "screen 2" (320x480)
how do I make that - did load app at position "screen 2" and after that
I can scroll not down, but to up at start launch app.

[image: for example]

How to release that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to give the scrollview a proper content size, depending on the screen size.

Assuming that the scrollview is fullscreen in portrait:

```
//------------------------------------------
- (void)viewDidLoad{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  CGRect screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

  [scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
  [scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(0, screenSize.size.height)];

}

//------------------------------------------

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];

  CGRect screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

  CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake( 0.0, screenSize.size.height / 2);

  [scroller setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: read OP question ?? OP want , how it possible when start App it automatically scroll at Second added view

Comment: is that SECOND view staying at the bottom of your scrollview?

Comment: yes, you can, but I prefer to make programmatically everything that's beyond the scrollview's frame

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
        self.YourSecondView.frame = CGRectMake("As You Need");
        [self.ScView addSubview:self.YourSecondView];

        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(self.YourSecondView.frame.origin.x,self.YourSecondView.frame.origin.y,self.YourSecondView.frame.size.width,self.YourSecondView.frame.size.height);        
        [self.ScView scrollRectToVisible:rect animated:YES];
   }
```